# flush water/latex paint residue down sump pit

Tags: painting, paint, sump-pump, acrylic

I know that to clean you brush from latex paint, you just clean it with water.

I have a little complication in that I don't have a sink in my garage :((

I'm wondering, can I simply flush the residue after cleaning the brush with water down the sump pit? Will it (the paint somehow) damage the sump pump or something?

Thanks

Comment: Thinking this over, it's probably not a good idea. This water in the sump pit doesn't move too much. It's better to go to my parents house and clean the brushes there. lol (they have a sink in the basement made for that more or less).

Comment: Or toss the brush in the trash.  I discard them all the time because I work in epoxies and LPUs.

Comment: I wash brushes and rollers with latex paint in them into the soil of my yard. I don't put even diluted latex paint in the sanitary sewer leading to the city sewer system. I fill a bucket outside in the yard soak the implements in that. I would like to know what is the recommended procedure for people with no yard, a highrise for example . . .

Comment: As an aside: garages often can have a "garden sink" with garden hose hook-up and drained via a length of hose to a dry well lined with a pvc tube.